# Reason for "AADSTS70000: Authentication failed. Delegation blob grant is malformed" error on SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-online, csom, authentication

When trying to get the `access_token` using the `refresh_token` for my SharePoint site using WebRequest i get the following error

> "AADSTS70000: Authentication failed. Delegation blob grant is
>   malformed".

I am making a POST call with the following parameters

1. grant_type
2. refresh_token
3. client_id
4. client_secret
5. resource

Sample Code:

```
        string sts = "https://accounts.accesscontrol.windows.net/db0540ee-834e-419a-bc68-09d1690d5a0e/tokens/OAuth/2";
        string requestString = "grant_type=refresh_token&refresh_token=[refreshTokenValue]&client_id=[clientId]&client_secret=[clientSecret]&resource=00000003-0000-0ff1-ce00-000000000000/myAccount.sharepoint.com@db0540ee-834e-419a-bc68-09d1690d5a0e";
        string tokenResponse;
        byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(requestString);

        WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(sts);
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;

        using (Stream reqStream = request.GetRequestStream())
        {
            reqStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
        }
        using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
        {
            using (Stream respStream = response.GetResponseStream())
            {
                using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(respStream))
                {
                    tokenResponse = reader.ReadToEnd();
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: how are you doing it ? can you share some sample code ?

Answer (score 0):

> AADSTS70000: The provided access grant is invalid or malformed.

The 70000 error is supposed occurred due to below reasons

1. one of your tokens is bad, my bet is refresh – or
2. your URL is incorrect – my bet here is the reply URL does not 100% match what you configured in Azure

**Malformed** – If anything is spelled incorrectly or out of place, like cleitn_id vs client_id or your redirect_url is https://service.contoso.com in the script but it’s to https://service.contoso.com/ with the slash on the end in Azure then you will get the AADSTS70000 error for being MALFORMED

For Details you can refer [Article written by Kevinm](http://www.happymillfam.com/aadsts70000-authentication-failed-authorization-code-is-malformed-or-invalid/).

Comment: Any Idea what causes the refresh token to go bad ?

Comment: Could you double check you passing parameter with your Azure register app. If there minor miss match then it's don't work.